# Saving files locally for offline access in Chrome APP

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

is it possible to download a file from a link like this "hxxp://abc.org/img.png" then save it in my local system. (The user should not select the directory or select it only once). Once the data is saved on client computer i can open that location and use any of the files ?

This is basically to run my application offline (chrome app).
I have seen the fileSystem API of chrome app , it can open a file and modify it but did not see how to download a file and save it.

Please guide how to achieve this objective.

Comment: Probably you could use `chrome.downloads.download` to download a URL. See more details here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download

Comment: @gui47 checked already , downloads API is compatible only with extensions not with chrome app

Comment: Well, to my best knowledge, there's not a similar Chrome API for chrome apps. I wonder maybe Html5 download attribute could help you out.

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Yes have read the developer.chrome docs ...

Answer (score 1):

I use fetch apt for this propouses.

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('pragma', 'no-cache');
    myHeaders.append('cache-control', 'no-cache');

    var myInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
    };   

    fetch(path, myInit)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.blob();
        })
        .then(function (myBlob) {
            File.system.root.getFile(filename, {create: true}, function (entry) {
                entry.createWriter(function (writer) {
                    writer.write(myBlob);....
```